# is there any windows forms application user interface themes rather than metro style

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I am looking for new styles of windows form applications.
Is there any style or something that looks cool like metro style.
Or any other way to create it rather than wpf

Comment: winforms doesn't support theming. Use WPF.

Comment: ok thanks. So i need to learn WPF now. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third-party user interface libraries from the big commercial vendors have different visual styles and will allow you to select from many options. Providers include companies such as...

- Infragistics
- Developer Express
- SyncFusion
- ComponentOne

...and probably several others as well.

Comment: Well we all want something for free. But if you want a professional piece of software in the UI space for Windows then you are pretty much limited to commercial options.

Comment: @PhilWright `if you want a professional piece of software in the UI space for Windows then you are pretty much limited to commercial options` - Sorry, far from true. You can create professional-looking .Net UIs for Windows by using WPF and not having to resort to expensive $1000 telerik stuff.

Comment: The question was specifically about WinForms.